# python programming for absolute beginners chapter 3, challenge 4

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm having a few thoughts about this challenge. I'm supposed to, instead of guess a number that the program is randomly picking from 1-100 this time myself pick a number randomly and have the program guess it.
So I made it work but its not exactly what I want it to be, here is what I got so far tho:

```
#I'm deciding to go with number 43.
import random

print("Hello computer, welcome to my guessing game!")
guess_list=[]
computer_guess=""
tries=1
while computer_guess!=43:
    computer_guess =(random.randint(1, 100))
        if computer_guess in guess_list:
        continue
    elif computer_guess==43:
    break
    else:
        print("Is the number you're thinking of ",computer_guess,"?")
        guess_list.append(computer_guess)
    tries+=1
print("I finally got it! Your number was 43 and it only took   me",tries,"tries!")
```

I kind of wanted to make it so that, based on what I reply the program understands( and repicks a number ) diffrently.
Basiclly I tried adding this:

```
    if response=="I'm thinking of a higher number, keep guessing!":
        computer_guess=(random.randint(int(computer_guess),100))
    if response=="I'm thinking of a lower number, keep guessing!":
        computer_guess=random.randint(1,int(computer_guess))
```

My thought was to answer based on its previous guess and have it correct itself("too high, or "too low"). I do understand I cant have computer_guess inside of computer_guess, but I'm not sure what to do here. If its worht mentioning I'm doing this on my sparetime so sadly I dont have any professor to ask on the subject. 
Should I just keep it simple or is it easy making this adjustment?
Thanks,

Etil

Comment: The basic algorithm for guessing games like this that gives decent accuracy is to keep track of the highest and lowest bounds that have been found, and guess half way between. So when you start, you know it's between 0 and 100. You guess half way at 50. Say that's too low. You now know it's between 50 and 100, so you guess 75. Say that's too high. Now you know it's between 50 and 75, so you guess 62, etc. Just keep track of the high and low bounds using two new variables.

Comment: Exactly what you are saying is what I wanted the program to do, but it wont with the simple code above. That's why I'm asking if its easy making it understand, based on what I reply...If it is to guess lower or higher numbers.

Comment: Read over my comment again to get a feel for it, then forget about programming for a second. Grab a pen and paper, and go through it manually. Think of what data you need to keep track of on the paper and what comparisons you need to make between different data. Then, translate that thought process into code. This is exactly the kind of problem to practice developing an algorithm with.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the computer must guess whatever numbers, the easiest solution would be for the computer to guess 1, if that isn't correct then guess 2 etc, but that would mean traversing all the numbers and asking n times the user for an answer (quite annoying).

FIRST: I would change your hardcoded 43 for a number that you choose.
THEN: You can make your program guess 1 by one (That works)

THEN: Explore more efficient solutions (e.g go to (max+min/2) and ask the user if higher, equal etc if higher reset your min to be ((max+min)/2) and do not touch max, if lower reset your max to be max+min/2 and repeat.
That is also way more efficient as you don't have to keep track of what the computer guessed, eventually it would get there.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Please note that `max+min/2` and `(max+min)/2` are not the same

Comment: ye quick typing changed that